# How to add option/ ListItem to dropdownlist dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to build my DDL dynamically,I get info from DB using JSON (I get the data with **no problem**) but couldn't show my data in my DDL...
I tried three different ways, nothing changed.. What am I doing wrong ?

//HTML

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="productDDL" runat="server" CssClass="ddl"></asp:DropDownList>
```

//Javascript

```
  function creatDDL(data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data.Data);
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                $("#productDDL").append("<option>" + obj[i].id + "' - '" + obj[i].name + "</option>");
             $("#productDDL").append("<option>"+obj[i].id + "' - '" + obj[i].name+"</option>");
                $("#productDDL").append($("<option></option>").html(obj[i].id + "' - '" + obj[i].name));

            }
        }
```

Comment: can you provide your json ?

Comment: sorry.. I am not allowed.. but I get the info I need with no problem..(checked with alerts) the JSON is fine.

Comment: yes. and I checked with alerts I get all I need the problem is adding the info to the dropdownlist

Comment: No I thought I must use it..

Comment: I tried it, no change

Comment: Is your code going inside the for loop or is it skipping it?

Comment: are you sure that rendered id is `#productDDL`? better use `$("#<%: productDDL.ClientID %>")`

Answer (score 0):

I like your third attempt best. Assuming your data is in order, you just need to brush up on the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/).

Here's a working version of what I gather you're trying to do:

```
function createDDL(data) {
  var options = $.parseJSON(data.Data);

  $.each(options, function(n, option) {
    var $option = $('<option />').text(option.name).val(option.id);
    $("#productDDL").append($option);
  });
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/Esr5q/